# Every random variable $X$ can be written as $X=\lambda Z_1+(1-\lambda)Z_2$, for $Z_1$ discrete and $Z_2$ continuous random variables.

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

Show that every random variable $X$ can be written as $$X=\lambda Z_1+(1-\lambda)Z_2$$
for a discrete random variable $Z_1$, a continuous random variable $Z_2$, and a real value $\lambda$.

This exercise was proposed in class. I really don't know if the result is true.

I know the trivial cases ($X$ discrete and $X$ continuous), but need help in the general case. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Are you sure the "mixing" is done to the values of the random variables (and not to the densities or distribution functions)? That is, $X$ equals $Z_1$ with probablity $\lambda$ or  $Z_2$ with prob $1-\lambda$  As stated, it doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: The statement is equivalent to every nondiscrete random variable being $X=Y+Z$ for some discrete random variable $Y$ and some continuous random variable $Z$. How to do this, say, if $P_X$ is the midpoint of the uniform distribution on $(0,1)$ and the Dirac measure at $2$?

Comment: Isn't the sum of a continuous random variable and a discrete random value also continuous? Am I missing something?

Comment: @user251257 If they are independent, yes, and possibly in more cases. But how is this relevant?

Comment: @Did I was wondering could $X$ be anything other then discrete or continuous.